# How can i access the database into the middleware

Tags: express, nestjs

I want to record the frequency of accessing the API. I want to insert every API access directly into the database through middleware. I don't know how to access the database in nestjs middleware.

The code will like:

```js
import { NestMiddleware, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

// console.log('StatisticsMiddleware');
@Injectable()
export class StatisticsMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
    // console.log(req.originalUrl, req.ip, req.connection.remoteAddress);
    const url = req.originalUrl
    const ip = req.ip || req.connection.remoteAddress

    // 
    Db.insert('LOG_TABLE', url, ip)
    next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A middleware class is just like any other `@Injectable()` class in NestJS, and as such can have the database injected into it. [The docs mention you can use injection like any other provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#dependency-injection), so all you'll need to do is provide your database connection (be it a Mongo Model, a TypeORM Repository, or anything else) and you'll be good to access from there.